# Rails - Dynamically Update Styles on Route Change

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to change the background image on an html element by updating the css class when the route changes. I'm using a helper function, as suggested in similar posts, but the css class is only applied when the page is reloaded. What's the best way to dynamically change css classes on route change?

***application.html.erb***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="<%= yield(:html_class) || '' %>">
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                              'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
...
```

***home.html.erb***

```
<% html_class 'nail' %>
```

***projects/index.html.erb***

```
<% html_class 'test' %> #only applied on page reload
```

***helpers/application_helper.rb***

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def html_class(class_name)
    content_for(:html_class) { class_name }
  end
end
```

Comment: Try attaching it to the body element instead.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!!